# Is there a CSS that can render variable height for each character depending on the height of a character?

Tags: css, typography

The CSS below,

```css
.message {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<display class='message'>ㄨㄢˊㄇㄢˇ</display>
```

produces this output. Notice the space beneath character `ˊ`:

[image]

Is there a CSS that can render individual characters based on their height, so that punctuations (e.g., period and comma) and accent characters won't take up space? The word above needs to be displayed as this instead:

[image]

The above will be used on CSS pseudo elements. Thus, wrapping each character in their own div or span is not feasible.

Problem details are here: *[zhuyin (bopomo) inconsistently aligned #10](https://github.com/chinese-words-separator/chinese-words-separator.github.io/issues/10#issuecomment-1457266661)*

For the question about trying different fonts:

I tried several fonts, and all of them still render accent characters (e.g., `ˊ`) with space underneath it. All of them basically produces this:

[image]

Here are all the fonts I've tried:

[image]

For the answers that advises to embed extra div/span, I need to emphasize as stated in the question that on my specific use case, div/span(any HTML tags for that matter) cannot be embedded in CSS pseudo elements.

As for the rationale for using CSS pseudo elements as an annotation mechanism (instead of say using `ruby` or combo of `div` and `span`), CSS pseudo elements is the only way to annotate text that the Chrome extension will not to interfere with browser's copy-paste (i.e., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) functionality and on functionality of 3rd-party Chrome extension dictionaries. The [Ruby](https://github.com/PabloRomanH/zhongzhong/issues/41) tag is not an option even if it can embed HTML. Ruby interferes too much with the browser's copy-paste and other dictionaries.

Using `span` and `div` for annotations will get their content being copied too when highlighting and copying the original text.

Try copying the original text in the link below. If the annotation mechanism is using tech, such as `ruby` and or `div/span`, those tags' content will get copied too:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G08ZZXDZJ7MX

Annotating text using CSS pseudo elements is the only option for a Chrome extension not to interfere with the browser's copy-paste functionality, and for it not to interfere with other third-party Chrome extensions too.

Here's how CSS pseudo elements is used in the code (Chrome extension) as annotator: *[Zhuyin (bopomo) intonations not displayed correctly when text is vertically aligned #9](https://github.com/chinese-words-separator/chinese-words-separator.github.io/issues/9#issuecomment-1452879797)*

Comment: I believe this may be built into the font's metrics. Have you tried using different fonts?

Comment: @Alohci Yes I've tried several different fonts, the fonts I've tried is on the edited question

Comment: removing `text-orientation: upright;` or with `unset` shows the apostroph with the expected height but it's not exactly the same glyph

Comment: If you have an element with `,` as its only content, it will occupy the same vertical space as other characters, so I expect `text-orientation: upright` to show extra space over the rendered part. Only the horizontal size can be different in the fonts I know.

But there may be special fonts, such that its "horizontal size" becomes your "vertical size" after 90 degrees of rotation; the "original rendering" of a character in this font is "sideways", so it appears upright after rotation. This reminds me of some old fonts with names starting with `@`, but I'm not sure if those are usable here.

Comment: @DiegoD But removing that will cause the text to re-orient to 90 degrees like its English letters counterpart, see the word Prologue here: https://github.com/chinese-words-separator/chinese-words-separator.github.io/issues/9#issuecomment-1452879797. Without `text-orientation: upright`, the character `ˇ` will re-orient to 90 degrees, making it look like a `<` character instead, likewise with other tones accent characters

Comment: @MichaelBuen yes and I'm sorry I only added noise to the discussion. I'm not familiar with this scenario .. I also tried to visit some japanese web site to earn some inspiration but nothing changed. The only suggestion I found was to change the font size of the single character wrapped inside an individual span but that's something you already know and was suggested already

Comment: one very last thing... wrapping those punctuation characters in their individual span and having a rule like this `.message span{display: inline-block;height: .5em;}` will trick the game without affecting the font size itself but just the height. I'm sure there's a native way to deal with it that asian people know and maybe it's related with fonts as other people suggested.

Comment: How about empty span elements that have pseudo-elements, like `<span data-pseudo="ㄨ"></span><span data-pseudo="ㄢ"></span><span class='accent' data-pseudo="ˊ"></span>`? With a css like `[data-pseudo]::before{content: attr(data-pseudo)}`

Comment: @qrsngky Thanks, but that will not be feasible, the annotation's granularity is by whole word (which is composed of multiple characters), not by each character. To get a better idea of the constraint (whole word is embedded in one pseudo element) I'm dealing with, see the HTML tags and CSS I used, in screenshots here: https://github.com/chinese-words-separator/chinese-words-separator.github.io/issues/9#issuecomment-1452879797

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, and it now looks more centered. It is not perfect though, but it is good enough not to confuse on which word the annotation belongs to.

I went with using a letter-spacing of `-0.20em` and with the [suggestion of Pablo V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75682045/is-there-a-css-that-can-render-variable-height-for-each-character-depending-on-t/75682346#75682346) to use traditional Chinese fonts. `Noto Serif TC` font is one good choice. The magic mostly comes from `Noto Serif TC` font.

#### Before

Take notice of the words `的`, `是`, `故事`, and `如何`. Their annotation look more top-aligned despite using `flex-direction: column-reverse; align-items: center`

[image]

#### After

I am still using `flex-direction: column-reverse; align-items: center`, but with `letter-spacing: -0.20em;` and `font-family: Noto Serif TC`.

Take notice of the words `的`, `是`, `故事`, and `如何`. Their annotations now look more vertically-centered as compared to before.

[image]

The letter-spacing `-0.20em` is not hard coded. The user can choose which font combination and letter-spacing (`Guide spacing`) gives the best result for them and their eyes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you something like this by specifying manually which character you need to adjust:

```css
.message {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  font-size: 2rem;

}
.accent {
  margin-bottom: -1.8rem;
}
```

```html
<display class='message'>ㄨㄢ<span class="accent">ˊ</span>ㄇㄢˇ</display>
```

Comment: That will not work on my specific use case. Already stated in the question: `The above will be used on CSS pseudo elements, wrapping each character in their own div or span is not feasible`. As for the rationale for using CSS pseudo elements, that is the only way that the Chrome extension won't interfere on browser's copy(Ctrl+C) functionality and on functionality of 3rd-party Chrome extension dictionaries. [ruby](https://github.com/PabloRomanH/zhongzhong/issues/41) tags is not even an option even if it can embed HTML, ruby interferes much with copy-paste and other dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

```css
.message {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<display class='message'>ㄨㄢˊㄇㄢˇ</display>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g.,  what did you change? Why did you change it? What was the outcome? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75683152/edit), not here in comments (****** ***without*** ****** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Did you change anything? Or is it a copy of the code in the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).